# CSV Files and Formatting to open in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

I have a CSV file but unfortunately, for some of the columns which have a comma in them, they have not enclosed it within double quotes, so when I open the CSV file some rows are all off by one column.

Is there a way that I can identify these rows and format them correctly so that I can open them. I am happy with a non-coding solution or even a coding solution.

Note: The column width cannot be used as they are all varying column width and no way to identify them distinctly.

Any help is appreciated!

**Screenshot #1:**

[image]

This is the CSV file. As you can see, the second row has a comma but doesn't have any double quotes around it. As a result, when I open this file in Excel, the following happens.

**Screenshot #2:**

[image]

So, the question is - How can I modify the file and then open it so that the right data is under the right column as shown below.

Screenshot #3: Desired Output

[image]

Comment: @pnuts: Yes, but when I set the delimiter in Excel (step 2 of 3 of the Text Import Wizard), it still identifies the row which has a comma in the column as having a delimiter and therefore the columns get offset by 1.

Comment: Help us to help you; **please update your question with a small example of your input data, your current output and your desired output.**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I have now added screenshots of CSV, the current output and the desired output. Thanks!